# Convert list to character in R

Tags: r, list, text

I want to unlist a list in R but to keep  the hole texts as one in each element of the list.

```
ID = c(rep(1,4),rep(2,3),rep(3,2),4,5);ID
VAR = c(rep("A",3),"B",rep("C",2),"D",rep("E",2),"F","G");VAR
D = data.frame(ID,VAR);D
X = aggregate(. ~ ID, unique(D), c)
```

if i unlist the list  X,  i will take each text separately and I do not want it.
I want the result from this aggregate() function to convert to a data frame (as.data.frame()) but to contain the same elements.Not as a list but as character.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(dplyr)
X %>% 
  mutate(VAR = sapply(VAR, toString))
#   ID  VAR
# 1  1 A, B
# 2  2 C, D
# 3  3    E
# 4  4    F
# 5  5    G

#OR
D %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(VAR = paste(unique(VAR), collapse = ','))
#      ID VAR  
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 A,B  
# 2     2 C,D  
# 3     3 E    
# 4     4 F    
# 5     5 G    

#OR based on comment, remove "," in collapse
D %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(VAR = paste(unique(VAR), collapse = ' '))
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#      ID VAR  
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 A B  
# 2     2 C D  
# 3     3 E    
# 4     4 F    
# 5     5 G
```

Comment: without the concatenate c(). To print it without the symbols in VAR variable.Only the texts.Keep in mind that I will extract to a xlsx file after I have  convert it to data.frame

Comment: so without the `,` e.g. `A B`?

Comment: Mmmm ok but if you convert it to data.frame the c() will appear?

Comment: see update. Can you supply expected output?

Comment: I don't want this c(\"MED12\", \"MED07\"). only to print  this text "MED12", "MED07".

Comment: what do you expect from the data you supplied in the question?

Comment: Excuse me.I don’t want to when I print the X to column variable VAR to print the c(\”A\,\”B\”).Just the A,B without the concrete are function c().Can you convert i the frame X to something else in order to print the wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the question is and what your expected output is, but if you want a single character in the **VAR** column, you can use `tidyr`'s `unnest` function.

```
tidyr::unnest(X, cols = VAR)
```

which will provide the following output

```
ID VAR  
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 A    
2     1 B    
3     2 C    
4     2 D    
5     3 E    
6     4 F    
7     5 G
```

Comment: no. The unnest() function will not do the job I want